# keep the vertical proportion of the video

Tags: html, css, video

I have a question, how can I do so that the inserted video keeps the vertical proportion (so that all the content is seen) and is not displayed with zoom.

```
<section class="ctn-video">
   <video class="video" muted autoplay loop controls >
      <source src="./img/LOREAL/Sequence 02_4.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   </video>
</section>
```

I tried changing the width and heigth but it didn't work.
I want that when I watch the video on the desktop it keeps the vertical proportion so all the content is shown

Comment: 'vertical proportion' isn't really meaningful. Do you mean that what is required is that all the video can be seen within the viewport, whatever the aspect ratios and sizes of the viewport and video?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS object-fit: contain to ensure all the video is always visible.

Here's a simple example:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  /* the dimensions can be anything, just set like this here for demo */
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

video {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<section class="ctn-video">
  <video class="video" muted autoplay loop controls>
                <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
</section>
```